# Make a program able to save data with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, database, save

I'd want to make a program that could save different values and store it in a file and, then that the user can open this file every time he wants to. Need some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for persistence. There are some options available:

```
1) Using SQLite
2) Use Core Data
3) Write it as text to file
```

Core Data is recommended.

Comment: I'm interested in using Core data, but I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Marcus Zarra Core data book http://pragprog.com/book/mzcd/core-data or video tutorial http://ideveloper.tv/video/coredatacourse.html Apple core data programming guide http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need complex persistence then you should use Core Data. If you are thinking about just saving a text typed by the user (as a NSString), use the following method:

```
writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:
```

You can alternatively save a NSArray into a plist file using the following method:

```
writeToFile:atomically:
```